# FCGX_Accept_r runs twice in simple FastCGI application on C

Tags: c, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to create simple FastCGI app written in C:

```
#include <fcgiapp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int sockfd = FCGX_OpenSocket("127.0.0.1:9000", 1024);
    FCGX_Request request;

    FCGX_Init();
    FCGX_InitRequest(&request, sockfd, 0);

    while (FCGX_Accept_r(&request) == 0)
    {
        printf("Accepted\n");
        FCGX_FPrintF(request.out, "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h1>Hello World!</h1>");
        FCGX_Finish_r(&request);
    }
}
```

It works fine - when i call it from browser, it displays page with "Hello World!" message.

The problem is that code inside a "while" works **twice**, i.e. I see following output in terminal:

```
[root@localhost example]$ ./hello 
Accepted 
Accepted
```

Why it prints "Accepted" twice per each request?
If I put real code here, e.g. query a DB, it will be executed twice as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What program are you using to make the web request? Some web clients may also request an e.g. `favicon.ico` file, which may account for the second request to the fcgi process:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2015:16:02:11 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 32 "-" "..."
127.0.0.1 - - [29/Aug/2015:16:02:11 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 32 "http://127.0.0.1/" "..."
```

This could be determined by inspecting the webserver logs, or adding debugging to the C program to show the request parameters. Using just `telnet` to request `GET / HTTP/1.0`, I do not see a double hit for a forward-everything-to-fcgi webserver configuration using the `nginx` webserver.

Comment: Haw! The five-year break from the web programming has an effect. The second one really was a request from the browser to a favicon. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, it was the first thing I tripped over, too.